# Can you set up an all-CPU-player game with no humans?

Tags: civilization-5

When you set up a new game in Civ V, it appears that there must always be at least one human player.

I was wondering if it was possible to set up a game with no human players - the [10-year Civ II experiment](http://www.pcgamer.com/2012/06/12/ten-year-game-of-civ-2-results-in-hellish-nightmare-planet-permanent-nuclear-war/) got me interested to see what would happen if the same thing were attempted in Civ V, and the easiest way to do so would be to allow a game with all-CPU players to run by itself whilst I go to the pub*, and later observe the results. Eternal world peace or Gandhipocalypse?

Is it possible to set up this kind of game? I will accept answers that require mods, as I don't believe it's possible with the vanilla game.

*(best place to be when casually simulating armageddon)